# How to expand only one collapsible at one time

Tags: react-native, expandablelistview, react-native-collapsible

I'm very new to react native. So the problem here now is I want to expand and collapse the view only one item at a time. Currently, every item expands and collapses simultaneously eventhough I only click at one item Any suggestions ? Below is my code and I have attached the screenshot of my screen.

```js
export default function AppCollapsible({ data }: { data: any }) {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true);
  const [multipeSelect, setMultipleSelect] = useState(false);

  const isExpanded = () => {
    if (collapsed) {
      setCollapsed(false);
    } else {
      setCollapsed(true);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {});
  return (
    <View style={styles.listContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={isExpanded}>
        <View style={styles.list}>
          <Text style={styles.accName}>Current / Savings</Text>
          <Text style={styles.accValue}>MYR 40,000</Text>

          <View style={styles.imageIcon}>
            <Image
              source={require('ngcc_poc/src/assets/icons/active/ChevronDown.png')}
            />
          </View>
          <Collapsible collapsed={collapsed} align="center">
            <CurrentSavingsCard />
          </Collapsible>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={isExpanded}>
        <View style={styles.list}>
          <Text style={styles.accName}>Fixed Deposit</Text>
          <Text style={styles.accValue}>MYR 180,000</Text>

          <View style={styles.imageIcon}>
            <Image
              source={require('ngcc_poc/src/assets/icons/active/ChevronDown.png')}
            />
          </View>
          <Collapsible collapsed={collapsed} align="center">
            <FixedDeposit />
          </Collapsible>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      
    </View>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not a complete answer but as a source of inspiration as @laurenyz suggested you.

You can have a look at this. I extracted the state logic to a new component **ToggleView**

```js
function ToggleView({name, value}) {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCollapsed(!collapsed)}>
      <View style={styles.list}>
        <Text style={styles.accName}>{name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.accValue}>{value}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

export default function AppCollapsible({ data }: { data: any }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.listContainer}>
      {
        data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <ToggleView 
              key={item.id}
              name={item.name}
              value={item.value}
            />
          )
        })
      }
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I got this error when trying your code "ERROR Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop". I kept the data in my json file which is every item has their own unique id

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - I can think of 2 options.

1. You can break them out into separate components so that they have separate `collapsed` values.
2. You could give them ids and set the active id with useState instead. If you want only one to be opened at a time, you could set the default value to "".
   `const [collapsedId, setCollapsedId] = useState("");
   If you wanted to be able to have multiple, you could set the default as an array and then add or remove items by their id onClick.